# printing a reference variable of Arraylist in java

Tags: java

I created a reference of ArrayList class and add few objects in arraylist.when i print reference of arraylist then how it prints liat of objects stored?More sprecifically a reference's hashcode should be printed

Comment: If you want the HashCode, use the hashcode method.

Comment: Why did you try? What was the result? What did you expect? It's as simple as `List list = ...; System.out.println(list);` To deeply understand what happened behind is not so easy I'd say, but you can check `Object.toString()` and also `String.valueOf()`.

Comment: [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString--): "Returns a string representation of this collection. The string representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (comma and space). Elements are converted to strings as by String.valueOf(Object)."

Comment: Note that the objects in your list might have overridden their `hashCode` method; if you want their original hash code, you can use `System.getIdentityHashcode(Object)`.